# Firefox Full-Screen Flash not Working

Tags: 13.10, firefox, video, flash

In Ubuntu Gnome 13.10, attempting to view Flash video full-screen does nothing but freeze the video. The freezing can be fixed by unfocusing and refocusing the window, but I cannot get Flash to go full-screen. However, when I view a (non-embedded) YouTube video, full-screen works fine.

Could anyone tell me how I can fix this? It seems strange that YouTube seems to (almost) work but nothing else.

In case you need them, here are my detailed system specs:

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: IdeaCentre K430 ()
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: Lenovo Product
    serial: ES09865757
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=desktop 
    keyboard_password=enabled power-on_password=disabled 
    uuid=C841A482-9BA0-E111-8F3C-043C2C3F2200
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       serial: ES09865757
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: 0
          version: E8KT24AUS
          date: 02/16/2012
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 2496KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd
          int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen 
          int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: c
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: d
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: internal varies
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: e
          size: 6MiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: internal varies unified
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: f
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 16KTF51264AZ-1G6M1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 0
             serial: 3A8979CA
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 16KTF51264AZ-1G6M1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 1
             serial: 3A8979E1
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 16KTF51264AZ-1G6M1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 2
             serial: 3A8979DD
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: 16KTF51264AZ-1G6M1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 3
             serial: 3A8979F8
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320 CPU @ 3.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 10
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2320 CPU @ 3.00GHz
          slot: SOCKET 0
          size: 1600MHz
          capacity: 1600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8
          apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss
          ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good 
          nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 
          monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt
          tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts
          dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express
             Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff 
             ioport:e8000000(size=167772160)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GF119 [GeForce GT 620 OEM]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list 
                rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff
                memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) 
                memory:f7000000-f707ffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: GF119 HDMI Audio Controller
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                version: a1
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f7080000-f7083fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:41 memory:f7100000-f710ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:44 memory:f711a000-f711a00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host 
             Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7118000-f71183ff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio 
             Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7110000-f7113fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:e0100000-e02fffff 
             ioport:e0300000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:d000(size=4096) ioport:f2100000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 06
                serial: 8c:89:a5:d2:af:86
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list 
                ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 
                1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169
                driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 
                03/27/12 ip=10.0.0.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII 
                speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:43 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f2104000-f2104fff 
                memory:f2100000-f2103fff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host 
             Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7117000-f71173ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Z75 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 
             [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:42 ioport:f070(size=8) ioport:f060(size=4) 
             ioport:f050(size=8) ioport:f040(size=4) ioport:f020(size=32) 
             memory:f7116000-f71167ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7115000-f71150ff ioport:f000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Hitachi HDS72302
             vendor: Hitachi
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: MN6O
             serial: MN1240FA0BS79D
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512 signature=2b17f296
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 4af3f545-ebaf-654d-aa76-4738368fe647
                size: 198MiB
                capacity: 200MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-05-18 04:49:53 
                filesystem=ntfs label=SYSTEM_DRV state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: 3.1
                serial: 166844d0-ea46-fc46-b388-d6d4aa30fbbd
                size: 1075GiB
                capacity: 1075GiB
                capabilities: primary ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-05-18 04:49:57 
                filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true 
                resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 80c8c3a4-0168-d24b-9e77-6d2343063263
                size: 24GiB
                capacity: 25GiB
                capabilities: primary boot ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2012-05-18 04:49:21 
                filesystem=ntfs label=LENOVO_PART state=clean
           *-volume:3
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                size: 762GiB
                capacity: 762GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume:0
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 15GiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-logicalvolume:1
                   description: Linux filesystem partition
                   physical id: 6
                   logical name: /dev/sda6
                   logical name: /
                   capacity: 9765MiB
                   configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 
                   mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 
                   state=mounted
              *-logicalvolume:2
                   description: Linux filesystem partition
                   physical id: 7
                   logical name: /dev/sda7
                   logical name: /home
                   capacity: 737GiB
                   configuration: mount.fstype=ext4 
                   mount.options=rw,relatime,data=ordered state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi3
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: BD-RE  BH30N
             vendor: HL-DT-ST
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 2.01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@2:1.7
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk:0
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: STORAGE DEVICE
             vendor: Generic
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: 0405
             serial: 000000000505
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
        *-disk:1
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: STORAGE DEVICE
             vendor: Generic
             physical id: 0.0.1
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.1
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             version: 0405
             serial: 000000000505
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=5 sectorsize=512
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdc
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: ham0
       serial: 7a:79:19:d8:63:42
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6
       duplex=full ip=25.216.99.66 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair 
       speed=10Mbit/s
```

Thanks for any help you can give me. This issue has been bugging me for a while and I'm finally fed up with it, so any solution would be a good solution considering how frustrated I am.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what isn't opening? you state it opens for youtube, but what wont it open in?

Comment: Full screen video will not execute. Instead, the video just freezes until the window is unfocused and refocused.

Comment: I have exactly the same issues with firefox and gnome-shell 3.12. My work-a-round for now is use google-chrome, but that's annoying.

Comment: @Willi Chrome does seem to help, but videos like those from Vimeo still act strangely.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a solution to this from Mozilla's website ( https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/flash-video-wont-play-full-screen )
It is enough that you add `env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libGL.so.1` before `firefox` in the launcher. Solved the issue for me without any alterations.

Answer (score 0):

So as you said, it could be an Adobe error,

1. Open terminal and type `sudo apt-get update`
2. then open software center and click "update" (something along that line)
   **it will show a list of things that can be upgraded**
3. scroll through to find either 'adobe', 'mozilla', 'media player', 'media runner', or 'full-screen command'.
4. update those if you find them
5. once they're all done, restart computer.
6. open terminal again and type `sudo apt-get update`
7. run Mozilla Firefox and you should be done!

Comment: I could not find an `update` option within Software Center. However, I did use Software Updater and was told my software was up-to-date (I did just update my software, yesterday, so this is no surprise).

Comment: When you open software center go to pakages and and it should be an option on that page

Comment: There is no packages option (keep in mind that I'm on `13.10`), but I did click "Installed." However, I found no menu or link for updates.

Comment: installed is correct, im loosing points! ugh :/ ok so im sorry i do not have ubuntu at this exact moment, i cant give precise names...